# Как достать версию релиза через github api?

Tags: javascript, php, git, github

Подскажите, или наставьте на путь истинный, как можно достать версию релиза проекта используя github api?
Чтобы на выходе у юзера была видна текущая версия релиза, например 0.1.9
Желательно на php или js.

Comment: версию релиза **чего**? уточните в тексте вопроса, нажав [edit].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ссылка куда надо делать запрос имеет вид:

[https://api.github.com/repos/ВЛАДЕЛЕЦ/НАЗВАНИЕРЕПОЗИТОРИЯ/releases](https://api.github.com/repos/%D0%92%D0%9B%D0%90%D0%94%D0%95%D0%9B%D0%95%D0%A6/%D0%9D%D0%90%D0%97%D0%92%D0%90%D0%9D%D0%98%D0%95%D0%A0%D0%95%D0%9F%D0%9E%D0%97%D0%98%D0%A2%D0%9E%D0%A0%D0%98%D0%AF/releases)

Запрос можете делать, хоть через CURL PHP, хоть через ajax js, как вам удобно.

**На примере репозитория OwlCarousel2.**

Делаем запрос на получение последнего релиза:

> https://api.github.com/repos/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/releases/latest

В ответ мы получим json массив где будет версия последнего релиза.

Если нужно получить вообще все релизы, то делаем запрос сюда:

> https://api.github.com/repos/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/releases